# Can't add string to a string type variable in Python

Tags: python, string, variables, addition

I wanted to make a very simple network scanner in python, and I wrote this:

```
import subprocess
ip_range = input("Enter ip range:")
start_ip = input("Enter start ip:")
end_ip = input("Enter end ip:")
result = "Result:"
for ping in range(int(start_ip), int(end_ip)):
    ip = ip_range + str(ping)
    connect = subprocess.call(["ping", "-c1",ip])
    if connect == 0:
        result += "---"
        result += "Ping to ",ip,"was OK"
        result += "---"
    else:
        result + "Couldn't ping to " + str(ip)
        result + "---"
        pass
print(result)
```

All of them work correct except one thing.
In this part

```
result + "Couldn't ping to " + str(ip)
result + "---"
```

The result doesn't add up to this code, I mean it just write result.

Comment: Look closely at the difference between the two branches of your `if` statement. You use two different operators.

Comment: result += "Couldn't ping to " + str(ip)
result += "---"

Answer (score 1):

`result + "Couldn't ping to " + str(ip)` is an expression, not a statement. You don't assign that value to `result`. Try changing the `+` to `+=`. That will store the value `result + "Couldn't ping to " + str(ip)` in `result`.

Comment: I tries += instead of + but the answere will be replace with the last value and doesn't add together.

Comment: @HoseinAzimi I don't understand your comment. Can you be more explicit about what code you are using and the output you are expecting?

Comment: I wanna user input a ip range and then script go and ping the ips and know what ips are
up and what ips are down,then add result to a string variable for example:
ip_range:192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.110
ping all of them was ok
result:--Ping to 192.168.1.100 was OK------Ping to 192.168.1.101 was OK------ etc.